# How to insert fields (with text) in libre office writer document

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I'm writing a document which contains "fields" (empty spaces to be filled on the moment) such as customer name, date, price etc... I noticed that if I line up underlines there is some gap left in between:

[image]

I tried applying underline style to it which look even worse. What is the correct way of inserting "fields" that are not objects to be filled in using PC but only after the document is printed?

Comment: What font and operating system is this?

Comment: @JimK using Lora (Google) font on W10

Answer (score 0):

Use a different font, at least for the underscores.  There are no gaps for the majority of the fonts I've tested, for example Liberation Serif.
[image: gaps]